# Any quick way for me to test my browser's hash rate for CryptoNight v2?

Tags: cryptonight, javascript

I want to test the rate at which a WebAssembly miner can calculate CryptoNight v2 hashes in my Chrome web browser (or what my browser's Monero hash rate would have been as of ~May 2018). Is there an easy way to do this?

I've tried to hack some open source GitHub repos, but it's just too much work.

Answer (score 1):

Given that Monero is now on CNv4, I doubt very much you're going to find a "quick" way to test this. You'd need to find or setup a version of the chain running the older version, setup a mining proxy, edit and build one of the CN wasm miners etc etc. So nothing "quick".

This all said, why do you need to test this? I can tell you right now that javascript mining gets you sub-100 Hs.

Comment: Retroactively calculating web browser mining profits for optimal choices of CryptoNight PoW currencies using historical data on CPU hashing capability on the device of average web visitor. 

I recognize your username, and I've made some attempts setting up a pool-miner-node infrastructure with your repositories. I'll try some more before I abandon the idea.

Comment: Which is near pointless. The differences will be negligible. The profitability of browser mining is really only affected by how *many* browsers are mining (how much traffic and how long people stay on a mining page). The difference in the various Monero CN variants has normally been <15%. So if you want to calculate browser mining profitability, you can just use an average 50hs and multiply by the visitor count and time on page.

Comment: My project is academic in nature, and the sole challenge is to quantify the market efficiency of CryptoNight hashing for various currencies. Like, on any given day during the past year, given network difficulty, block reward, CryptoNight version, USD market price, market liquidity and momentary average consumer CPU hash output, what would the optimal currency be, and how much greater would the profits be versus the worst currency and XMR. My hypothesis is that the market has been _somewhat_ efficient, and it seems you agree, but it still needs testing if I ever want to graduate.

Comment: By this comment (your definition of what you want to quantify), you don't need to break down how efficient *browser* mining is by currency. Profitability of *mining* can be historically obtained by data on the blockchain, e.g. you can calculate based on a blocks difficulty, timestamp, tx fees and coinbase emission. Then use an average electricity cost at the block time and you can then work out profitability.

Comment: Yeah there's a bit more. It has to be in the context of revenue models for web content providers, newspapers etc., because reasons reasons. If I'm not mistaken, the hash rate advantage of desktop vs web browser has fluctuated quite a bit. I even need to compare pre-WebAssembly vs WebAssembly.

Comment: As for the mining profit estimate you propose, how would it work when I compare across different currencies who roll out new CryptoNight iterations independently? Has the hash rate of consumer grade CPUs been so stable across different CryptoNight variants that you think it negligible? My scope has been more ambitious until now, opting to model average web visitor CPU hash rate in the past, based on the Firefox public data report. (You would have several upvotes by now if I had sufficient reputation)